# Drupal hook_preprocess_hook not working

Tags: hooks, theming

I have a webform with id 32.

I created a template (which works fine) in my theme/templates folder named webform-form-32.tpl.php.

I also created a preprocess function in my template.php file. My theme is called emuse and my hook is:

```
function emuse_preprocess_webform_form_32(&$vars){
}
```

but this doesnt get called. Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Nealv, the preprocess function can only be implemented for the base name, not for the additional suggestions you used for creating your tpl.php file.
The suggestions for alternate template files are added in the preprocess functions themselves.

See https://drupal.org/node/223440 - These naming suggestions are set from preprocess functions.

So call THEMENAME_preprocess_webform_form and check if it's the right form to alter within the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_webform_form(&$vars){
  print_r($vars);
}
```

For reference : http://www.ixis.co.uk/blog/webformblock-styling

Hope it helps